# ImportError: No module named rospkg

Tags: ros, gazebo, spawn-model, gazebo-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

After installing ROS on my Ubuntu, I was trying to follow the tutorials under the simulator_gazebo. But I have gotten an error message for this command:

```
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file `pwd`/object.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model my_object
```

Error message:

```
ImportError: No module named rospkg
```

Could it be from the installation? I think everything went well during the installation.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39657/importerror:-no-module-named-rospkg/) by [Zara](https://answers.ros.org/users/2831/zara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2012-07-24

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-24**:
Did you install Electric or Fuerte?

**Comment by [Zara](https://answers.ros.org/users/2831/zara/) on 2012-07-24**:
I followed instruction through this link http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu. I guess it is Fuerte.

**Comment by [Zara](https://answers.ros.org/users/2831/zara/) on 2012-07-26**:
I am posting the entire message. Also version of python on my system is 2.7.1.
Any help?

> > rosrun gazebo spawn_model
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/spawn_model", line 7, in 
> > import roslib, time
> > File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/**init**.py", line 50, in 
> > from roslib.launcher import load_manifest
> > File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in 
> > import rospkg
> > ImportError: No module named rospkg

**Comment by [pjusesros](https://answers.ros.org/users/55469/pjusesros/) on 2020-06-03**:
This can also happen if you are running the file with the wrong python interpreter. This might be the first thing you notice as import rospy is often the first import in a file. Not the problem here but this may be useful for others looking later

**Comment by [KearaB](https://answers.ros.org/users/55832/kearab/) on 2020-06-17**:
This should go as an edit to your original question.

**Comment by [minhaj](https://answers.ros.org/users/72920/minhaj/) on 2021-04-05**:
thanks pjusesros. i forgot that i had set pyenv global python to be python3.8
after changing it to system python version everything worked fine. thanks for saving me from what otherwise was going to be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [accepted answer (as of Feb 2017)](http://answers.ros.org/question/39657/importerror-no-module-named-rospkg/?answer=40589#post-id-40589) is outdated.
Unless you need to customize, using binary is strongly recommended IMO. See the [instruction on ros wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rospkg#Installing_rospkg) for how to install.

---

**UPDATE 2019-02-02**: Looks like this is still a popular question. `apt` worked for 18.04 for me on a docker container that I just pulled from online.

```
$ docker pull ros:melodic-ros-core
melodic-ros-core: Pulling from library/ros
Digest: sha256:206a3a506cda320b525ef2cf2587726ee01451f470be4dfdd80cd20693840f27
Status: Image is up to date for ros:melodic-ros-core
$ docker run -it ros:melodic-ros-core /bin/bash

# apt-get purge python-rospkg && apt-get update && apt-get install -y ipython python-rospkg
:
Unpacking python-rospkg (1.1.7-100) ...
Setting up python-rospkg (1.1.7-100) ...

root@4a5281183177:/# ipython
:
In [1]: import rospkg
In [2]: rp = rospkg.RosPack()
In [3]:
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-01**:
I've just made your answer the accepted one. Could you expand your answer with how users are expected to install binaries of `rospkg`?

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-07-31**:
Even with `rospkg` installed I still have the issue on Kubntu 18.04. Changing the `PYTHONPATH` variable solves the issue.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-31**:
If you've installed everything from binaries *and* are using the system, default Python 2 installation, everything should-just-work. If it doesn't, and you have to change `PYTHONPATH`, something is wrong and you should resolve it.
@130s answer is correct, and I don't think the downvote is justified.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-07-31**:
@VictorLamoine I second to @gvdhoorn. Although I'm not sure how similar/same `kubuntu` is to any OSes ROS supports, any issues for the released binary must be fixed w/o adhoc workaround IMO. Maybe file at [ros-infrastructure/rospkg](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rospkg/issues).

**Comment by [naveenk.medi](https://answers.ros.org/users/37305/naveenk.medi/) on 2018-09-05**:
Even after installing via `apt-get` I am getting the same error. `$ which python` produces
 `/home/userName/anaconda3/bin/python` .

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-09-08**:
@naveenk.medi  Please open a new question with more detail.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2019-01-31**:
`apt-get` did not work for me on Ubuntu 18.04, `pip install` did. I think this answer would benefit from copy-pasting the instructions here, too.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

since Fuerte, rospkg is standalone, so you will have to install it seperately e.g. by source:

$ git clone git://github.com/ros/rospkg.git
$ python setup.py install --user

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [endamaco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2861/endamaco/) on 2012-08-05**:
Ok, that worked! Thanks!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-08-06**:
If you have added the ros sources you can apt-get install python-rospkg

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2012-08-20**:
Can you be more clearer? What worked well, I have the same problem

**Comment by [Shanker](https://answers.ros.org/users/156/shanker/) on 2012-09-27**:
I am also interested in your solution. I have a similar question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/44669/fuerte-no-module-named-rospkg/ . I have used the solution suggested here: install rospkg, but that does not suffice for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason this error occurs is because Python packages in /opt are added to PYTHONPATH environment variable BUT for ones in /usr, path does not exist in PYTHONPATH variable. The python-rospkg gets installed in /usr by default. So you just need following line in .bashrc to fix this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

---

Originally posted by [sytelus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26598/sytelus/) with karma: 201 on 2016-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahmed Abdalla](https://answers.ros.org/users/25274/ahmed-abdalla/) on 2016-06-10**:
Hi :)
I'm having issues because I'm using anaconda...I get an error because of the different PYTHONPATH used by anaconda.
How can I use Anaconda with ROS?

**Comment by [mark2n](https://answers.ros.org/users/27081/mark2n/) on 2017-02-23**:
I have a same situation with @Ahmed Abdalla. The issue was solved by following [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40159908/3941772).

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2017-12-10**:
This answer worked for me in ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks!

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-03-02**:
This made be encounter the error `no module named _internal` afterwards, that is, I couldn't use `pip` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did `pip install rospkg` since I have anaconda. It worked.

(as a side note, for some packages I also got "No module named Em", for which I used `pip install empy`)

---

Originally posted by [pridanks](https://answers.ros.org/users/29100/pridanks/) with karma: 176 on 2017-01-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kun](https://answers.ros.org/users/29796/kun/) on 2017-03-23**:
Thank you，It's useful for me. I am trying to build the turtlebot_rapps.

**Comment by [aniket0112](https://answers.ros.org/users/33856/aniket0112/) on 2018-04-09**:
Worked for me. I installed rospkg and catkin_package via pip

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update 06/04/2022:

When using Ubuntu 20.04, which uses python3 install `python3-rospkg`.

---

Previous (alternative) solution (not recommended anymore):

I am using ROS noetic on Ubuntu 20.04 which uses python3. To fix the error, in my case I had to install

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

---

Originally posted by [fjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/9816/fjp/) with karma: 200 on 2020-10-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arunj18](https://answers.ros.org/users/65431/arunj18/) on 2020-12-12**:
This worked for me, running noetic on Ubuntu 20.04.

**Comment by [MiJi](https://answers.ros.org/users/71781/miji/) on 2021-03-11**:
Great. This worked for me.
Same problem with ROS noetic on Ubuntu 20.04

**Comment by [Anjulo](https://answers.ros.org/users/57623/anjulo/) on 2021-07-28**:
Yeah, it worked for me too. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296790/python-is-python3-package-in-ubuntu-20-04-what-is-it-and-what-does-it-actually) is an explanation of what it does

**Comment by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on 2022-02-01**:
What you should rather do, is to install `python3-rospkg`. (I am using noetic on 20.04, and that is what I did.)